# Drawing text in a canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I need to draw text in a canvas, but the current `fillText` implementation overcomplicates a lot of features that I need (like being able to draw multiple lines).

Because I need to copy the pixels from the canvas later, it must be drawn in the canvas, it can't be a `span` element over the canvas.

Being able to make it editable is a plus, but not required.

Is there any library that provides advanced features to draw text in a canvas? (It must work at least on IE9, Firefox, Chrome and Opera)

Answer (score 0):

I only know of the [FLOT Canvas Text plugin for jquery](http://lessaworld.com/projects/flotCanvasText/).

But if I were you I'd still do it with a `<span>` because it would then be Search Engine friendly. You can easily get the text of a span (or most) elements using element.innerHTML or element.innerText depending on the object. then you can process/pass that. e.g. for a span such as

```
<span id="myspan"> lorem ipsum </span>
```

I can say

```
spanText = document.getElementById("myspan").innerText;
```

Comment: I'm gonna take a look at it. About the <span>, as I said, it must be rendered in the canvas, because the canvas is going to be uploaded to a image service.

Comment: There is a plugin: HTMLtoCanvas (http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/). You pass it the DOM and it parses it and creates a canvas snapshot locally using only javascript. You can then submit a screenshot from canvas, Although to me, it would make more sense to do the whole thing serverside to begin with